# Encoding in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I got a problem with encoding in my web project. Here is a part of the backing bean.

```
this.searchword ="NA2F"
Query query = db.query();
query.constrain(sbasUserList.class);
 query.descend("groupname").constrain(this.searchword).like();
   res = query.execute();
    this.searchresult.addAll(res);
```

It works as it should. seachresult is filled with some object.
The first line is just for debugging, in real *searchword* is modified via JSF on an web page. 
If I type *NA2F* into the form add send it the searchresult is 0.

Is ths something about encoding?

Regards 
Ralf

Comment: Should be more a Java question than a JSF...

Comment: Why exactly do you think that it's JSF's fault? Have you debugged the value of `searchword`?